# Adding/Removing MetaColumn from MetaTable

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-data, metatable

I'd like to add/remove a column from MetaTable. But `table.Column` is of type `ReadOnlycollection<MetaColumn>`.
How can I modify, add or remove a column from the table?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ScaffoldColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx)?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
[TableGroupName("Foo")]
    public partial class Foo 
{ 

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public string MyNewColumnNotinDBTable
        {
            get
            {
                return "FooBar";
            }
        }
}



 public class FooMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]     // hide Id column
        public object Id { get; set; }


        public object Name { get; set; }

        public object MyNewColumnNotinDBTable { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Well, fortunately, I have been able to remove a column from the table. The real deal is about adding a custom column to it.

Comment: So are you trying to "remove" a column (as the question indicates) or "add a custom column" (as your comment indicates)?

Comment: @Ash Machine: Sorry, forgot to update the title when editing.

Comment: OK.   I showed how to remove(Id), I showed you how to "Add" the column(Name).  Now, how do you wish to "modify" the column?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because of showinf me how to hide a column. Well, I didn't get the "Add Column" part. I want to add a column which is not already in the table's column collection. Something like `datatable1.Columns.Add`. `ScaffoldColumn` allows us to show/hide a column which is already in the column collection of the table.

Comment: Added example MyNewColumnNotInDBTable